# Selenium 2.53.1 now working with latest Firefox versions?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver.io

My organization is stuck on Selenium 2.53.1, and we test using compatible Firefox 46.0.1.

I recently accidentally ran a test with Windows 10, Selenium 2.53.1 and Firefox 61.0.2, and the test ran fine. This was completely unexpected.

Has anyone else tried this? I imagine even if it worked for this one case, it wouldn't be recommended in general, though tempted to try a run against our whole test suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out, webdriver was still running Firefox 46.0.1.

Firefox 46.0.1 was installed to 
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe".

The new firefox installed to 
  "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe".

It appears that I can't manually start Firefox 46.0.1, due to the way the firefox profile manager works - my profile got updated to the new firefox install. But webdriver must not use profiles, as it can still run the old firefox.

I should be able to do some profilemanager trickery so I can also use either firefox.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1170758